# is QIN Leather, used for smartphone cases, vegan?

Tags: veganism, leather, animal-by-products

Recently I have been looking at smartphone cases and I am not sure what to make of what the QIN leather means when listed as a material. In some of the products, there is explicitly written QIN PU leather, where PU should mean [polyurethane (bicast) leather](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicast_leather) which seems to be using animal leather but most of the adverts omit the PU part.

To give an idea, I was looking at covers for ASUS Zenfone 3 (ZE552KL), such as [this one](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/NILLKIN-QIN-Leather-Smart-View-Wallet-Cover-Case-For-ASUS-Zenfone-3-ZE552KL-S001-/302148057424?var=&hash=item46596d7950:m:meExuC8NSNfj6LTxfP2WWJA), but for future reference, any cover that shows up when searching for Nillkin QIN leather case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeing as how the only google results for "QIN leather" reference the Nillkin products, one can only assume that QIN is part of the brand name and not an actual material. The material itself seems to be PU leather which as you mentioned, is partially composed of animal hide.

Comment: Do you have another source other than google search?

Comment: @Riker What source does one find for the non-existence of a material?

Answer (score 0):

I just bought a Nilkin Qin leather phone case and I can tell you it is pure PU there's no leather involved whatsoever.
Sorry for the late response.

Comment: Source for your statement that it is not leather?